# How to keep the numbering when using \usepackage{titlesec}

Tags: spacing, numbering, titlesec

I want to change the Sections and subsection spacing, therefore I use "\usepackage{titlesec}". However, at the moment I import the "**titlesec**" package I lose my section and subsection numbering.

I am aware of the "*titleformat*", however, I have not been able to combine the *spacing* and the *format* together in order to have numbering and the spacing I add to my example.

I must add that I'm compiling in Ubuntu 16, using TeXMaker.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{8pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{8pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{2pt}{8pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}


\sloppy %avoid word passing the limits of page aligment.
\begin{document}


\chapter{uno prueva} 
\section{uno Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{dos Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{tres Section}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{dos prueva}
\section{uno Section}q
qsdfdqsf
\section{dos Section}
qsdf
\section{tres Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

### EDIT 1:

As Requested by @egreg I added \listfiles at the beginning of the document and here they are the log results:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.11.1)  24 JAN 2018 14:28 entering
extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.

 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) 

  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text

titlesec.sty    2016/03/15 v2.10.1 Sectioning titles
 ***********
```

Comment: I get the numbers. Can you please add `\listfiles` at the top of the code, recompile and show here the first four lines of the log file and also the ones at the end from `*File List*` to `***********`?

Comment: @egreg I add this information as an Edit of the question.

Comment: OK, as I suspected you have a buggy version of `titlesec`. If you can't update your TeX Live (because Debian doesn't allow you to), you can use the easy workaround in my answer to the question this is a duplicate of (just copy in your document the lines in the first code section).